# How to split the code into different chunks?

Tags: r

I'm new to R. When I write an R script, I want to split the code into several chunks so that I can execute a specific chunk instead of the whole script. I googled but I didn't find any useful answer. I'm not talking about code chunks in R markdown. For instance, in Python, I can split the code and create a new chunk by inserting

```
#%%
```

in the beginnig of a new line. How can I do it in R?

Comment: one workaround is to use backets `{ }` so that the lines behave as a single chunck

Comment: if you really want to have code with chunks, you should use jupyternotebook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more of an editor / IDE feature. In RStudio you can create code sections through comments that include 4 or more `-`, `=`, or `#` characters - https://docs.posit.co/ide/user/ide/guide/code/code-sections.html#code-sections

The default shortcut in Windows for a new section is <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+R</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+T</kbd> for current section execution. Code snippets (there's already `ts`) and code palette are also quite convenient for creating new sections.

```r
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
message("untitled")

# foobar ------------------------------------------------------------------
message("foobar")

# Sun Feb  4 10:19:34 2024 ------------------------------
message("'ts' snippet")
```

[image: RStdui creenshot]